# Vim, Tabular and Ruby 1.9 Hashes

Tags: vim, hash, alignment, tabular, ruby-1.9

Assuming I have the following options Hash as an argument to a method in Ruby 1.9.x:

```
my_method :arg1,
  some_option: "value 1"
  some_other_option:true
  option_three: 123
```

Using the Tabular VIM plugin, what would the regular expression be to get the options Hash align like so:

```
my_method :arg1,
  some_option:       "value 1"
  some_other_option: true
  option_three:      123
```

The `:` has to stay attached to the key, unlike with, for example, JSON.

Perhaps a more visually appealing style would be this instead, which looks more aligned:

```
my_method :arg1,
        some_option: "value 1"
  some_other_option: true
       option_three: 123
```

Does anyone by any chance know how to accomplish either of these alignments using Tabular?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In order to get the first alignment, one can use the command

```
:Tab/\w:\zs/l0l1
```

For aligning hash keys to the right, it seems inevitable to select
only the lines containing them before applying a `:Tabular` command,

```
:Tab/\w:\zs/r0l1l0
```

Comment: Note that these commands correctly handle cases when method call arguments or hash values contain symbols (like `:arg1` in the question's example snippet).

Comment: This only works if there is a single `:` character per line, however

Answer (score 1):

I use Tabular a lot but I've never found the occasion to try its "advanced" features. A case similar to your example is presented in `:help tabular`:

```
:Tabularize /,/r1c1l0

        Some short phrase , some other phrase
A much longer phrase here , and another long phrase
```

which makes use of what it calls "format specifiers".

So, applying this command to the options (after visual selection) will do the trick:

```
:'<,'>Tabularize /:/r1c1l0

my_method :arg1,
        some_option : "value 1"
  some_other_option : true
       option_three : 123
```

Note to self: play more with Tabular.